# MS CRM and silverlight

Tags: silverlight, dynamics-crm-4

Is it possible to use a Silverlight control inside a CRM form? Either versions 4.0 or 2011.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes.  2011 allows you to embed silverlight controls via web resources directly in the page. The canonical hello world version of that is here:  http://www.dynamicslight.com/2010/10/building-silverlight-web-resources-for-crm-2011part-1/

You can also use Silverlight w/ CRM 4.0 via IFrames, using the URL of the iframe to pass in the necessary GUIDs to your app.

http://crm.davidyack.com/journal/2009/11/18/mixing-silverlight-4-with-dynamics-crm.html